# Accreative operator in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and  $H$ be a Hilbert space such that $X$ is embedded in $H$. By a duality map, $\phi_{x}$, defined on $X$, we mean any linear functional
$$\phi_{x} \in \left\{f \in X'\ \hbox{such
that} \ \langle x, f\rangle = \|x\|^{2}_{X},~~ x \in X\right\},$$

where $\langle,\rangle$ is the natural pairing between a
Banach space and its dual.

Let $J : H \rightarrow H'$ be the standard conjugate isomorphism
between a Hilbert space and its dual, so that $\langle x, J(x)\rangle = \langle x, x\rangle_{H} = \|x\|^{2}_{H}.$

We define the special duality map of $X$ associated with $H$ by
$$\displaystyle\phi_{x}^{s}
= \frac{\|x\|^{2}_{X}}{\|x\|^{2}_{H}} J(x).$$
 $\phi_{x}^{s}$ is a duality map for $X$. We say that a bounded operator $A$ on $X$ is accreative if $\langle A x, \phi_{x}^{s}\rangle \geq 0$ for all $x\in X$.

If $V$ is accreative operator such that $V-I$ is accreative, can we say that $V$ is invertible?

Comment: How are you considering both $\|x\|_X$ and $\|x\|_H$, is $X$ embedded in $H$?

Comment: Yes, $X$ is embedded in $H$

Comment: If $V$ is accreative operator such that $V-I$ is accreative, can we say that $V$ is invertible?

Comment: Is the embedding isometric? If not, then $\phi_x^s$ need not be a duality map for $X$. If yes, there is no point in writing $\|x\|_X/\|x\|_H$.

Comment: @sandwich $$\phi_x^s(x)=\frac{\|x\|^2_X}{\|x\|^2_H} J(x)(x)=\|x\|_X^2$$ and if the inclusion has norm $≤1$ you also have $$|J(x)(x')|≤\|x\|_H \|x'\|_H≤\|x\|_H \|x'\|_X$$ and $$|\phi_x^s(x')|≤\frac{\|x\|_X^2}{\|x\|_H} \|x'\|_X≤\|x\|_X \cdot \|x'\|X$$